# ElastAlert ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert

I'm having trouble running elastalert. This is the error I'm getting.
[image]

I'm able to create an index, but I'm not sure what I'm missing as I can't run it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I just deleted my blist and ran `pip install blist` and it fixes it. Not sure why my blist was broken in the first place, but a fresh new install fixed it.